# Android - Declare widget in manifest

Tags: android, widget, manifest

I have 1 android app project and 1 widget project, they all work fine. Now, i want to include widget project to android app project in order to when user install application, the widget will be installed too. I did like below but it did not work. Any helps?
Thanks you!

In manifest file:

```
<application>
    ............ (this is of android app project. below is of widget).......
    <receiver android:name=".widget.PlayerWidgetActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/playerwidgetprovider" />
  </receiver>
  <service android:name=".widget.PlayerWidgetActivity$UpdateService" /> 
  <service android:name=".widget.PlayerWidgetActivity$ServiceBindUnbindService" />  
</application>
```

`EDIT`: My application is quite big (.APK ~ 10MB), of course it has many activity, many services, many broadcast receivers, ..... so it takes times to build.
I create a new very small application with just an activity and put the code for widget like i put on the big app above. It works! OMG! Why it worked on that small app but not my big app :(

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".activity.ApplicationWithWidgetActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".widget.PlayerWidgetActivity" 
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/appwidget_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />             

    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/playerwidgetprovider" />
</receiver>
<service android:name=".widget.PlayerWidgetActivity$UpdateService" />   
<service android:name=".widget.PlayerWidgetActivity$ServiceBindUnbindService" />    

</application>
```

Comment: I know you would have done this many times , but check your package names in project and manifest both are same or not for widget package?, have you got playerwidgetprovider in xml folder?,Its confirmed that problem is either copying code to project or declaring in manifest..chill..just have a check again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had same problem!

The solution is - **INSTALLING APPLICATION INTO PHONE**.

Just move application to phone and you will see your widget.

Hope it helps you!

Info from here: http://www.hrupin.com/2012/07/how-to-fix-android-homescreen-widget-installation-widget-as-part-of-android-application